# prevent multi page form against bots

Tags: php, forms, security

I try to design a save reset-password-page for my scripts. I got very far, but now I could need some help. What I got already:

1. user puts his mail into a form and the script is sending him a mail with a url the user have to open. parameters: usertype, userid, token.
2. if the users visits the url he will get to a page, with a form where the token is already inserted. he only needs to click "proceed".
3. third page shows a form to change the password.

Now I'm a little doubtful with the security of this script. Lets say the attacker knows the mail, the usertype and the userid (would only be people with login, but its possible to know all that). He can now send a password-reset-link to users mail. Not a problem so far. 
But he knows that there is a token generated now and can try to brutforce it. For this he calls the 2nd or 3rd page with the known parameters and just trys every token.

To prevent this I put a captcha in the 2nd-page.

But now I need to protect the 3rd page/form. For now I give the token and check it a 2nd time. Thats not nice and makes the 1st-captcha just useless. Giving it another captcha would  be possible, but not userfriendly. Checking the captcha after 3rd form is filled is also not userfriendly.

So how can I make sure, the users passed the token-page (with captcha) in my script. So that the user can not just send a POST (e.g. with curl) with input-data of my 3rd-form (the password-change-form).

Thank you in advance.

**2nd-form**

```
<form name="confirm" method="GET">
<p>
<label for="confirm">Token
<input type="text" name="confirm" id="confirm_code"
<?php
if(isset($_GET['confirm'])) echo ' value="'.$_GET['confirm'].'"';
?>
></label>
</p>
<p><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="X" data-callback="checked" data-size="invisible"></div></p>
<p style="text-align:center;">
<input type="submit" value="Proceed">
</p>
<?php
echo '<input type="hidden" name="usertype" value="'.$_GET['usertype'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="'.$_GET['userid'].'">';
echo '</form>';
```

**3rd-form**

```
<form name="change" method="post">
<p>
<label for="pw">New pw
<input type="password" name="pw" id="pw"></label>
</p><p><label for="pw_repeat">Repeat
<input type="password" name="pw_r" id="pw_repeat"></label>
</p><p style="text-align:center;">
<input type="hidden" name="usertype" value="<?php echo $_GET['usertype']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_GET['userid']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="change" value="Change now">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Look up i) two factor authentication. ii) Cross site Request Forgery prevention and iii) using session data across pages.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that. I will read XSRF and prevent it with sessions i think. Sorry for the noob-question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I too am a programmer who is getting started and I work mostly on logins and stuff. 
Here are my Suggestions:

1. Add an algorithm that generates some automatic key purely on random basis.
2. Produce a link based on that random piece of key and a specified set of values(keep that a secret) and also make sure the final generated link is pretty big.
3. At the second page make sure you ask for a key (You'd send this key straight to his email along with the page link) i.e., the random generated key and then the algorithm magically decrypts to see if the underlying data is the same based on some values attached to his account or something else.
4. Make sure the link expires in the time needed to brute force through the page

If you can make sure above steps are followed correctly, then even with a bit of discomfort to the user your security will be pretty good. What do you think?

Cheers,
Rj